# on click events not working properly in Angular 5

Tags: jquery, html, typescript, angular5

I have a screenshot below which I have replicated in HTML/CSS.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sny53y5x/7/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot. The fiddle is working in a way that **when I hit on items waiting text, it changes into items received text and vice-versa**.

Now, I have used the code mentioned in the fiddle in my angular component. The **snippets of the angular component which I have used in my code** is shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
   <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">2</td>
   <td class="right-itemswaiting" (click)="textChange()">
      <div class="fold" data-filled="true">
         <div class="square white"></div>
         <span class="items-text">Items Waiting</span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Typescript:

```
export class AdminManageAttendeesComponent implements OnInit 
{
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}


textChange(){    
$(document).on('click', '.fold', function(e) {
var filled = !($(this).data('filled'));
$(this).data('filled', filled);
$(this).find(".items-text").text(filled ? "Items Waiting" : "Items Received");
$(this).find(".square").toggleClass("white", filled);
});
}
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

The above fiddle is working perfectly fine **but when I used it in my angular component, the text change happens on double click** but in the fiddle it happens on a single click.

I am not sure how to make fiddle in angular otherwise it would be easier for me to show whats going on exactly.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in my code above so that the text change happens on a single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this without jquery would be like this:

```
   <td class="right-itemswaiting" (click)="filled=!filled">
      <div class="fold" data-filled="true">
         <div class="square" [class.white]="!filled"></div>
         <span #text class="items-text">{{this.filled ?'Items Received': 'Items Waiting'}}</span>
      </div>
   </td>
```

The text can be optimised with a method, of course.
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbqw3i)

Comment: I tried with that. I think its a much better way as text changes on click of a colored box but it seems like `the text in the box seems to be making wierd shape on click`. The text change did happen on a single click but the text shapes changes rapidly.

Comment: You mean when you click quickly multiple times, there is a background shadow?

Comment: yes, you got it. When I click multiple times I can see some background shadow.

Comment: Is there any way, I can get rid of that ?

Comment: Yes, it's mouse select effect (blue background when you double click on a text so you can copy). Check out the demo and its css file

Comment: Thats better now. I didn't have a look at the CSS. I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Great :) I changed the css a few sec ago, it wasn't there before

Comment: One last question. By default, `items waiting text should have unfilled white square box` whereas `items received text should have unfilled white square box`.

Comment: [class.white]="!filled" should take care of it :)

Comment: The code in the fiddle is different from the one you have pasted here. Do you want me to use the code pasted here ?

Comment: One last question. I want to do the same for the `items received` text row. I have updated your [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjsnts?file=app/app.component.html). In the fiddle, the changes in both the row happens only on clicking on the bottom row.

Comment: On the first I guess you forgot ! sign, should be  (click)="filled=!filled". But for the app logic I am not sure it's the same 'filled' should be used

Comment: Thanks. It looks good. Suppose I have another row with the same `Items Received Text` then should I be doing the same thing as I did [here](https://angular-dgm15k.stackblitz.io) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168867/discussion-between-vega-and-user5447339).

Answer (score 1):

That implementation is as far from angular as possible.

Do something like this: I'm going to add some pseudocode.

```
<checkbox [(ngModel)]="isReceived" (ngModelChange)="someFun()"></checkbox>
<label> {{isReceived ? 'Items Received' : 'Items Waiting'}}</label>
```

in your typescript file,

```
isReceived: boolean;

constructor() {
   this.isReceived = initializeLogic() || false;
}

initializeLogic(): boolean {
    //if you want to initialize it any other way.
}

someFun() {
//do any other logic (not UI) associated with model change.
}
```

While you are at it, I'd suggest checking out the angular tutorial to get more familiar with the framework.

Comment: I will try to follow your logic. I am wondering why in my above code, the text change happens on double click as it working perfectly fine on fiddle.